# NSBorderlessWindowMask Subview NSTextfield not keybard editable Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, nswindow, nstextfield, keywindow

I'm using a NSBorderlessWindowMask for my main window on a Swift project (without storyboards), when I load a Subview, the NSTextfield outlet is not keybard editable. I already put this code on the initialisation:

> ```
> self.window?.makeKeyWindow()
> self.window?.becomeKeyWindow()
> ```

this allows the outlet to be "blue" like on focus, but the keyboard editing is disabled, i can copy/paste on the textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an awesome workaround for this problem: 
basically setup at beginning the NSWindow mask as NSTitledWindowMask, when application is loaded, remove set up the new mask NSBorderlessWindowMask

```
   func applicationWillFinishLaunching(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.window?.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden
        self.window?.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask // adds title bar
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        self.window?.makeKeyWindow()
        self.window?.becomeKeyWindow()
        self.window.setIsVisible(true)
        self.window?.styleMask = NSBorderlessWindowMask // removes title bar
    }
```

Comment: The documentation of `becomeKeyWindow` says "never invoke this method directly".

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a custom subclass of `NSWindow` and override `canBecomeKeyWindow()` to return true. By default, it returns false for windows without title bars (as documented).

You probably want to do the same for `canBecomeMainWindow()`.

Also, never call `becomeKeyWindow()` (except to call `super` in an override). That is called by Cocoa to inform the window that it has become the key window. It does not instruct the window to become the key window.